# jQuery Toggle Fahrenheit/Celsius

Tags: javascript, jquery, openweathermap

I'm trying to create a weather app with the Open Weather Map API. I want to create a button that will allow you to toggle between Fahrenheit and Celsius. I've tried literally everything but I've gone back to the code I wrote before I tried putting a button in.

How could I implement this with my current setup?

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="jumbotron text-center" 
style="background-color: #00F0F8FF; font-family: 'Oswald', sans-
serif; color: black;">
        <h1>Local Weather App</h1>
        <h2><span id="town"></span></h2>
        <h2>Temperture: <span id="temp"></span></h2>
        <div id="weatherIconBox"></div>
        <h2><span id="weatherType"></span></h2>
        <button type="submit" id="btn1">F&#176;</button>
        <button type="submit" id="btn2">C&#176;</button>

    </div>
</div>

var getIP = 'http://ip-api.com/json/';
var openWeatherMap = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
$.getJSON(getIP).done(function(location) {
$.getJSON(openWeatherMap, {
    lat: location.lat,
    lon: location.lon,
    units: "imperial",    
}).done(function(data) {
    $('#town').html(data.name);
    $('#temp').prepend(Math.floor(data.main.temp) + '&#176;');
$('#weatherType').html(data.weather[0].description).css('textTransform', 'capitalize');
$('#weatherIconBox').prepend('<img id="weatherIcon"     src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + data.weather[0].icon +     '.png"/>');

    });
});
```

Comment: In the example I have two buttons but I want to do this with just one button I was just experimenting and forgot to switch it back.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwqzBj?editors=1011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also using the API to create a side project.

Can you try this. By default display the data in Fahrenheit. And when you click the Celcius toggle button. Do a simple math calculation. I think the equation is ((f + 40) ÷ 1.8) − 40 = c. Then display this value.

Comment: F.Y.I another trick to do this is. Have 2 buttons. But when one is active (e.g Celcius) hide the other. So when you click on Celcius button, show the value. Then hide the Celicius. show the Fahrenheit button. Trigger the display of Fahrenheit value

Answer (score 2):

When you click the "#temp" element, this code will toggle the text between celsius and fahrenheit

```js
var cToF = function(c) {
  return (c * (9/5)) + 32;
};

var fToC = function(f) {
  return (f - 32) * (5/9);
};

$("#temp").on("click", function() {
  var isF = $(this).data("units") === "f";

  var oldTemp = $(this).text();
  var newTemp = isF ? fToC(oldTemp) : cToF(oldTemp);
  $(this).text(newTemp);

  var newUnits = isF ? "c" : "f";
  $(this).data("units", newUnits).attr("data-units", newUnits);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Temperature: <span id="temp" data-units="f">100</span></h2>
```

```
<h2>Temperture: <span id="temp"></span></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Be cautious about the math calculation...
You have to apply the right formula!

Here is a simple toggle button doing the math.

```js
var temp = "c";
var tempEl = $('#temp');

$("#tempToggle").on("click",function(){
  
  // Get actual shown temperature
  var tempVal = parseFloat(tempEl.val());
  
  if(temp=="f"){
    temp="c";
    // Calculate
    var converted = (tempVal-32)/(9/5);
    // Set
    tempEl.val(converted.toFixed(1));
    $(this).html("C&#176;");
  }else{
    temp="f";
    // Calculate
    var converted = (tempVal*1.8)+32;
    // Set
    tempEl.val(converted.toFixed(1));
    $(this).html("F&#176;");
  }
});
```

```css
#temp{
  width:3.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="temp" value="20.5"> 
<button type="button" id="tempToggle">C&#176;</button>
```